# Existence of random variable with particular Laplace transform

Tags: probability

I have a question about $\alpha-$stable random variable and I want to have your opinion on it: of course if $\sigma(\alpha)$ is an $\alpha-$stable random variable of positive values, for some $\alpha\in(0,1)$,  its Laplace Transform is given by 
$$E(\exp(-\lambda\sigma(\alpha)))=\exp(-\lambda^{\alpha}),\quad\lambda\geq 0.$$

Do you know if there exists a random variable $X$ such that $$E(\exp(\lambda X))=\exp(\lambda^{\alpha}),\quad\lambda\geq 0?$$
If yes, do you have it explicitly or by a theoretical result ?
Thank you very much.

Comment: The random variable $X$ can not depend on $\lambda$

Comment: Then I guess the question is not posed correctly (at least for me)

Comment: Is it more clear we this formulation : I search if there exists a random variable $X$ Such that its Laplace transform $L_X$ sastifies :  for all $t\geq 0$, $$L_X(t)=(E[\exp(t X)])=\exp(t^{\alpha}) $$

Comment: Now I understand the question. I tried to use that $e^{t^\alpha}=\sum_n \frac{(t^\alpha)^n}{n!}$ but with no success (actually this path would be inclined to suggest that such random variable would not exist). It is difficult for me to find such random variable. Perhaps one way to go is to use Euler's formula.